# Conditional Appcenter Codepush based on Environment?

Tags: react-native-code-push

Hi i'm using React Native Code Push currently.

Currently my code is manually handling it because of the need to prevent it from codepushing builds that are in the staging / testing environment. I had a problem earlier when i did a release build for testing, it still picked up the codepush and it refreshed incorrectly.

What is everyone else doing? I can make the codepushoptions on app resume but it'd still pick up the codepush bundle on my staging environments when i only want it on production :/

I considered the staging, and production environments in codepush but that part is quite confusing. not sure if its used at all.

```
let codePushOptions = { checkFrequency: codePush.CheckFrequency.MANUAL };
```

And in the code

```
if ((!(__DEV__)) && (API_BASE_URL === 'https://production.xxx')) {   // only run in production

    codePush.sync({
      updateDialog: null,
      installMode: codePush.InstallMode.ON_NEXT_RESTART
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

eh i found that i'd just set different keys per environment and codepush will handle that way.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=waatVm6-bX4